# Получить значение переменной с другой страницы на JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Допустим, есть 2 страницы index1 и index2, получаю значение переменной таким образом: `$('#class')` на странице index1, вот только блок с таким `id` лежит на странице index2, каким образом можно получить значение?

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду обмен информацией между открытыми табами, то простейшее - куки.
Если index2 может быть и никогда не открывалась, то надо ее открыть, например, в iframe.
Но у меня подозрение, что вы что-то делаете не так, в этом случае создаете index3, который возвращает вам данные на обе страницы.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wormhole.js есть такой клёвый плагин, например.